# How can I resize WebGLTexture with keeping content?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I would like to resize a WebGLTexture that is rendered by binding with Framebuffer previous frame.

I tried to resize this texture using texImage2D with new size and keeping formats and type.

I know this wont work. This maybe generate new texture with the size cleared with [0,0,0,0] for entire pixels.

How can I resize WebGLTexture with keeping content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't resize a texture in WebGL and not lose its content. You need to allocate another texture with desired size and copy old texture's data to it. There's two ways to do that: via a `copyTexSubImage2D` call or via a draw call. Note that the first way requires the old texture to be linked to a framebuffer, and the second one — the new texture.

Let's assume that your WebGL context is `gl`, the old texture is `oldTexture`, framebuffer it's linked to is `oldFramebuffer`, new texture is `newTexture` and its framebuffer is `newFramebuffer`.

With `copyTexSubImage2D` you can do something like this:

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, oldFramebuffer);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, oldTexture);
gl.copyTexSubImage2D(
    gl.TEXTTURE_2D,
    0,
    offsetInNewTextureX,
    offsetInNewTextureY,
    offsetInOldTextureX,
    offsetInOldTextureY,
    width,
    height
);
```

And done! Note though that this method won't allow you to manipulate texture data, just to copy it pixel-to-pixel.

The second way is a bit more complex and require some shaders that I won't list here. Basically, you need to setup your context to draw a textured quad.

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, oldTexture);
gl.uniform1i(shaderTextureUniformLocation, 0);

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, newFramebuffer);
gl.drawArrays(/* ... */); // Draw the quad.
```

That way you'll also be able to manipulate copied data, i.e. stretch it.

> I tried to resize this texture using texImage2D with new size and
>   keeping formats and type.
>
> I know this wont work. This maybe generate new texture with the size
>   cleared with [0,0,0,0] for entire pixels.

Yep, you're exactly right here.

Comment: `copyTexSubImage` is not guaranteed to be able to copy a texture. It copies from a framebuffer attachment but not all textures can be attached to framebuffers